# 301 redirect dynamic cgi generated urls using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cgi

I'm having trouble making sense of this .htaccess file I've inherited at my new job. I'm a graphic designer / marketer learning web development. Our site has a bunch of duplication errors and I want to rename our links and have them 301 redirected.

This is the first part of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine Off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog.asseenontvhot10.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sitemap\.xml

AddType text/html .shtml, .html, .htm


AddHandler server-parsed .shtml, .html, .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .shtml
#Options FollowSymLinks Includes -Indexes
```

From what I understand the first part links our blog to the main site, and I'm not sure what the next line does. 
The addtype line and the ones that follow enable .htaccess to read/write those filetypes?

Here is the part that I believe is relevant and what I need to change:

```
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{http_host}/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule default.html /home.html
RewriteRule contact\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=contact
RewriteRule about\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about
RewriteRule register\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?register=action
RewriteRule products\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?listcategories
RewriteRule parent_category/(.*)/(.*)/ /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?listcategories=action&parent=$1
RewriteRule category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&category=$1&page=$3
RewriteRule category/(.*)/(.*)/ /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&category=$1
RewriteRule category/(.*).html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&page=$1
RewriteRule product/(.*)/(.*)/ /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=$1
RewriteRule basket\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=basket
RewriteRule log-in\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?login
RewriteRule home\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=home
RewriteRule search\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=search
RewriteRule all-items\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search
RewriteRule update_user\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?displayuser=action
RewriteRule order_history\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?orderhistory
RewriteRule logout\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?logout
RewriteRule specials\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?search=action&keywords=nav_specials
```

I know the first part forces www. and does a 301 redirect, even though I haven't seen this way of accomplishing it on any guide I've read. The first thing I really need to change is making the home page 301 redirect from:
http://www.asseenontvhot10.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=home
to
http://www.asseenontvhot10.com/

So far as I can tell the RewriteRule makes this an option but dosn't force it. Will adding [r=301] to the end of the rewriterule work? 
I've also read that there is code you need to add for .cgi to work as .php does but I'm totally lost there.

---

Update:
I tried adding this line to the bottom -

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=home /
```

and I got a 500 error.

---

2nd Update:
I added this code:

```
RewriteRule about\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^display=about$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi$ /about [R=301]
```

And it 404'd. When I replaced the .htaccess file with the back up and the about page still 404's... Now I'm really at a loss and don't know how to revert the site. I don't even know where the redirect would be stored outside of the htaccess file once it's reverted.

---

3rd Update: (making progress)
I added this code:

```
RewriteRule about\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^display=about$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi$ /about\.html? [R=301]
```

and I got a redirect loop. It was finally redirecting to about.html which I thought the first rule renamed /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about to, but it redirected to it over and over again.

Comment: `Add*` had nothing to do with rewriting. that's just telling apache what the types of certain file extensions are. e.g. `AddType text/html .exe` would let you name your .html files as .exe instead and they'd be served up as html, not executables.

Comment: and `[r=301]` just tells the rewrite engine to do a client-side redirect, instead of a purely in-server rewrite

Comment: So my add type rule tells the server to serve .html files as either .shtml, .html, or .htm? Is there a reason for this, such as mac compatibility?

As far as the redirect, would adding [r=301] to the end of the rule make the browser and search engine crawlers redirect the cgi links to a clean link?

Comment: all it does is tell the server that .htm, .html, and .shtml are of type html, which normally means they're fired out the door without any server-side processing. as for the rewrite rules, the ONLY rule that'd be visible to crawlers would be the r=301 one. everything else would be internal only, e.g. undoing the "friendly url" into the internal "dirty" ones.

Comment: does the fact that the site goes through cgi mean that I need to add anything to the .htaccess file?

Thank you for the help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive in Apache requires that the redirect destination be a fully qualified URL with a scheme and a URL. So this would work:

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi http://www.yourdomain.com/
```

However, I don't believe that `Redirect` can check the query string, so in order to only apply this redirect if the query string is "display=home" you will probably have to use mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^display=home$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi$ / [R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` checks that the query string exactly equals "display=home" and the `RewriteRule` will only trigger if this condition is met. And in the `RewriteRule` the `[R=301]` flag instructs mod_rewrite to redirect the visitor's web browser to the target path, `/` in this case.

By the way, looking at the existing conditions in your .htaccess file, I can't see how your users are seeing the /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi path in their web browser. All of those `RewriteRule` directives are for silent rewrites. This means that the user will continue to see the "friendly" URL in their web browser, but in the background Apache will actually find the file located at the /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi path and return the content or result of that file to the user. So your users should already be seeing the friendly version of the URL. If what you are trying to do instead is silently rewrite a request for "/" (site root) so that Apache silently rewrites the path and actually fetches the content in the real file /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=home then you probably want this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=home
```

This will only match a request for the root directory (with no filename specified) and will silently fetch and return the content which results from calling the commerce.cgi file with a "display=home" parameter.

Comment: I added this code:

`RewriteRule about\.html /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^display=about$` 
`RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi$ /about\.html? [R=301]`

and I got a redirect loop. It was finally redirecting to about.html which I thought the first rule renamed /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about to, but it redirected to it over and over again.

Comment: The mod_rewrite directives are applied to every request, including to the rewritten requests. So telling Apache to rewrite A as B, and also B as A will cause an infinite loop. I don't recommend redirecting the user if they request the real URL. Instead just add a [canonical link element](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to your HTML pages so that search engines like Google know that this is just another way of finding the same resource.

Comment: Is that what I'm doing in this file? I really just want the `/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=about` to redirect to /about.html  
  
  Same with the categories and the home.

Comment: I don't think I can add canonical link elements to the cgi-bin pages. I'm pretty sure the way it works is that it pulls up the page referred to by PDG (our merchant program) and uses their link. I can change a few links in our .html pages but some links are generated by PDG and link to the cgi-bin.